# How do I center memoir's chapterprecis?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapterprecis{Bar}
\end{document}
```

How do I center "Bar" horizontally on the page?

[image: chapterprecis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand*{\precisfont}{\normalfont\itshape\centering}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapterprecis{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask where you found the info?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard I just looked in `memoir.cls`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought you could just look for LaTeX answers in your own head ;P

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard the definition of how chapterprecis works is listed on page 93 of the memoir manual, it is just a quote env, so David's solution is the easiest method.